# Compiler activity during recursion; answer needed to aid comprehension.

Tags: recursion, functional-programming

What happens with the stack calls and so on and so forth when executing a recursive function? Does recursion even use a stack in the first place? I would appreciate an answer that helps to visualize better what happens during recursion.

Comment: There is nothing special about recursion. A recursive function call is just like any other function call.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, a recursive call is the same as any other function call. It creates a new stack frame, saves old variables and ultimately returns to the caller, just like any old function call. This means that a recursive function *can* cause a stack overflow. (In fact, that's probably the easiest way to overflow your stack!)

In some languages, however, there is an exception for **tail recursion**. Tail recursion involves a recursive call that is the very last thing a function does (ie a call in **tail position**). This means the function can't do *anything* to the result of the recursive call except returning it directly. Compare these two silly examples:

```
// Not tail-recursive: we add 1 to the result of foo()
function foo(x) {
  if (x > 0) {
    return 1 + foo(x - 1)
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

// Tail recursive: we return foo() directly
// (`x - 1' happens *before* foo is called)
function foo(x) {
  if (x > 0) {
    return foo(x - 1);
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

If a function is tail recursive, there is not point in allocating a stack frame at each iteration since no information needs to be preserved. Instead, the existing stack frame can be reused or the whole thing can be rewritten into a loop.

Some languages like Scala do this, which means you can write iterative procedures in a recursive style without hitting stack overflows.

However, there is really nothing special about recursion. If a function call is in tail position, we don't need the stack even if it's a call to a different function. We can just implement tail calls as jumps. This is mandated by certain languages (like Scheme) but cannot be implemented in Scala because of Java compatibility reasons.
Proper tail calls like this are important for enabling mutual recursion and [continuation passing style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) without worrying about stack overflows.

So really, there is nothing fundamentally special about recursive calls as opposed to normal calls except that certain languages can only optimize *direct* recursion in tail position, not tail calls in general.